# How to edit the watch window in Visual Studio to zoom in or use larger text?

Tags: visual-studio

I have Visual Studio set up with larger text for the code, as shown in this partial screen capture image:

[image: Partial Visual Studio Window]

How can I increase the text size in the "Watch" window (also shown) to match?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. Select **Tools** -> **Options**.
2. Under **Environment**, select **Fonts and Colors**.
3. In the dropdown at the top, select **Watch, Locals, and Autos Tools
   Windows**.
4. Adjust the font size to your satisfaction.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Multidimensional Arrays
int[,] array = new int[6, 99];
Then you can use array to get what you want

Please see reference document
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/multidimensional-arrays

Comment: Multi dimensional arrays aren't in the scope of the question... I think that you may have answered the wrong question. :)

Comment: Whatever you're up to – do not disregard the importance of multidimensional arrays!